# NSColorWell subclass not getting mouseMoved events

Tags: cocoa, events, subclass, nsview, custom-view

I'm trying to implement a color picker in my Cocoa app. (Yes, I know about NSColorPanel. I don't like it very much. The point of rolling my own is that I think I can do better.)

Here's a picture of the current state of my picker.

[image: Custom viewness!]
<sub>(source: [ryanballantyne.name](http://ryanballantyne.name/forumstuff/color-picker-shot.jpg))</sub>

The wells surrounding the color wheel are NSColorWell subclasses. They are instantiated programmatically and added to the color wheel view (an NSView subclass) by calling addSubView on the color wheel class.

I want to make it so that you can drag the color wells around by their grab handles. The start of that journey is making the cursor change to an open hand when the mouse hovers over the handles. Sadly, [I can't use a cursor rect for this because most of my views are rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211277/why-shouldnt-i-use-a-cursor-rect-on-a-rotated-nsview-subclass). I must therefore use mouseMoved events and do the hit detection myself.

Here's the mouse event code I'm trying to make work:

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"I am over here!\n");

    [super mouseMoved:event];

    NSPoint eventPoint = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    BOOL isInHandle = [grabHandle containsPoint:eventPoint];
    if (isInHandle && [NSCursor currentCursor] != [NSCursor openHandCursor])  {
        [[NSCursor openHandCursor] push];
    }
    else if (!isInHandle)  [NSCursor pop];
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)event
{
    [[self window] setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
}
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent*)event
{
    [[self window] setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:NO];
    [NSCursor pop];
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

I find that my mouseMoved method is never called. Ditto for entered and exited. However, when I implement mouseDown, that one *does* get called, so at least some events are getting to me, just not the ones I want.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why not make an NSColorPicker subclass? Then, not only does your picker add to the existing Color Panel instead of throwing away its features, but if you want, you can even export it as a plug-in so that the user can use your awesome color picker in any application.

Comment: I've thought about doing that in future versions. First I need to prove to myself that my idea for a better color picker is going to pan out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mouseEntered: and mouseExited: don't track entering/exiting your view directly; they track entering/exiting any tracking areas you've established in your view.  The relevant methods are `-addTrackingRect:owner:userData:assumeInside:` and `-removeTrackingRect:`.  Just pass `[self bounds]` for the first parameter if you want your whole view to be tracked.  If your app is 10.5+ only, you should probably use NSTrackingArea instead as it directly supports getting mouse-moved events only inside the tracking area.

Keep in mind that 1) tracking rects have the same somewhat odd behavior as cursor rects w/r/t rotated views, and 2) if your bounds change (not merely your frame) you'll probably need to re-establish your tracking rect, so save the tracking rect's tag to remove it later.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about NSTrackingArea; I'll definitely check that out.